# kendo ui grid batchedit fire event after in cell edit

Tags: kendo-grid

I have created grid with remote bound datasource. I have used batch editing. One column is having amount. I want an event - which is being fired after in cell amount is updated. I tried with change event of DataSource but its not getting fired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  edit event when you're defining the grid  and then define blur to do something after leave and end editing cell or keyup to do something for each typing in the input.

for example :

```
 $("#personel").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            navigatable: true,          
            toolbar: ["create", "cancel"],
            columns:gridColumns,
            editable: "incell",
            edit: function(e) {
                var input = e.container.find(".k-input");

                 input.blur(function() {
                        .... your code ....
                 });

                 input.keyup(function(e) {
                        .... your code ....
                 });
             }});
```